# Exclusão em lote usando Linq

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho uma tabela, que é usada no meu `Model.edmx`, com os seguintes campos:

```
ID
ID_PROJETO
ID_ITEM
VALOR
```

Como converter o SQL abaixo em uma expressão Linq?

```
DELETE FROM TB_RECEITA WHERE ID_PROJETO = 100 AND ID_ITEM = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há o método [`DeleteAllOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb763521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Nunca usei esse método, mas ele é mais ou menos assim:

```
var receitas = (from r in contexto.Receitas
   where r.ProjetoId == 100 && r.ItemId == 5
   select r).ToList();

contexto.Receitas.DeleteAllOnSubmit(receitas);
contexto.SubmitChanges();
```

Para quem não usa Linq (apenas métodos de extensão), o código manual abaixo é uma solução:

```
foreach (var objeto in contexto.Receitas.Where(r => r.ProjetoId == 100 && r.ItemId == 5))
{
    contexto.Receitas.DeleteObject(objeto);
}

contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Você pode também implementar uma extensão da seguinte forma:

```
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
{
    public static void DeleteAllObjects<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> dbset, IEnumerable<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class {
        foreach (var objeto in data.ToList()) 
            dbset.DeleteObject(objeto);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
contexto.Receitas.DeleteAllObjects(contexto.Receitas.Where(r => r.ProjetoId == 100 && r.ItemId == 5));
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Usei a opção "código manual" e funcionou. Valeu. Agora só mais um dúvida: tentei usar `DeleteAllOnSubmit` e retorna o erro "does not a definition ...". Porque ocorre isto?

Comment: Acho que isso é tema de outra pergunta.

Comment: Ok. Vou criar um post. Mais uma obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo:

```
using (Entities conexaoEF = new Entities())
{
     // 1 - Seleciona a entidade no banco a qual se quer apagar. 'receitaParaDeletar'
     var receitaParaDeletar = conexaoEF.TB_RECEITA.Single(c => c.ID_PROJETO == 100 && c.ID_ITEM = 5);

     // 2 - Passa a entidade atraves do metodo 'Remove' dentro do contexto do seu Edmx.
     conexaoEF.TB_RECEITA.Remove(receitaParaDeletar);

     // 3 - Efetua as alterações.
     conexaoEF.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas retornou o seguinte erro: A sequência contém mais de um elemento na execução do filtro.E não disponibiliza a opção .Remove. No exemplo esta `&& c.ID_ITEM = 5` e deveria ser `&& c.ID_ITEM == 5`.